# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0 in Vuex

Tags: vue.js, local-storage, state, vuex4

I am sending data from vuex to localStorage, and then trying to set data from localStorage to state 'cart'.

```js
import axios from 'axios'
import { createStore } from 'vuex'

export default createStore({
  state: {
    cart: [],
    products: []
  },
  getters: {
    cart: state => {
      return state.cart
    },
    products: state => {
      return state.products
    }
  },
  mutations: {
    addToCart(state, product) {
      localStorage.carts = JSON.stringify(product)
      return state.cart.push(product)
    },
    removeProduct(state, item) {
      localStorage.removeItem('carts', item)
      return state.cart.pop()
    },
    SET_PRODUCTS(state, products) {
      state.products = products
      state.filteredProducts = products
    }
  },
  actions: {
    addToCart(context, product) {
      context.commit('addToCart', product)
    },
    removeProduct(context, item) {
      context.commit('removeProduct', item)
    },
    fetchProducts({ commit }) {
      return axios.get('http://localhost:3000/products?_limit=4&_page=1').then(res => {
        commit('SET_PRODUCTS', res.data)
      })
    }
  }
})
```

I have tried adding this line to the state cart

```
cart: [JSON.parse(localStorage.carts)]
```

but this only works if localStorage is not empty(if it already has something), if not it will throw error

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
```

Cart component:

```
<template>
    <div class="cart-container">
        <div class="header">
            <p>NARUZDBA</p>
            <div>
                <img src="../assets/icons/close.png" class="icon" @click="this.$store.commit('customChange')" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="products" v-for="item in cart" :key="item.id">
            <div class="product">
                <div>
                    <p class="amount">1x</p>
                    <p>{{ item.name }}</p>
                    <icon name="remove" class="remove" @click="removeProduct(item)"></icon>
                </div>
                <p class="price">{{ item.price }}kn</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <router-link to="/cart">
            <button class="btn">Kosarica</button>
        </router-link>
        <div class="outside" @click="away"></div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapState } from 'vuex'
import Icon from './icons/Icon.vue'

export default {
    components: { Icon },
    methods: {
        away() {
            this.$store.commit('customChange')
        },
        removeProduct(item) {
            this.$store.commit('removeProduct', item)
        }
    },
    computed: {
        ...mapState(['cart'])
    }
}
</script>
```

This is now showing '1x', remove button, and 'kn'

Comment: well the error say that your json sting starts with the letter 'u', thats not valid JSON, so why not display whats in that string (console.log?) - that will give you a clue as to whats going on

Comment: There's a couple of issues, SET_PRODUCTS attempts to add in a property on the Vuex store. In addition, filtered products sounds like it could just be a computed property when needed. removeProduct -- the localStorage.removeItem only has one parameter. The "pop" should really be replaced with a array.splice with the index. Add to cart should use localStorage.setItem and instead it should be adding to the JSONified array, not replacing it. Lastly, the return statements are unnecessary and the functions should (in my preference) be void

Comment: Also all of this could be fixed by using the updated vue store -- pinia and the package pinia-persistedstate from npm

Comment: I think this is an expected behaviour. JSON.parse() needs a truthy value (non-empty string, non-null, not undefined). you can catch those cases with: `cart: [JSON.parse(localStorage.carts || "[]")]`

Comment: @Issayah, Is there a way to solve this without pinia? Also all of these issues that you mention above, are not affecting my error i guess?

Comment: @IgorMoraru , almost. It actually gets rid of error i was getting, but now when page is loaded in my Cart component i see hardcoded data for the product. Thank you for helping.

Comment: The reason why you're getting the issue is because when you don't have information in the store, it's going to throw an error because you're trying to pass in undefined into JSON.parse -- hence the 'u'. What do you mean "hardcoded data"? We'd need to see the component in order to help with that one

Comment: Cart component code added.

Comment: Can you show us how `carts` looks like when it exits? Is it an object, Is it an array?

Comment: The whole point here is that `JSON.parse(undefined)` and `JSON.parse("")` will throw an error. The exact error you're seeing. `JSON.parse("[]")`. `JSON.parse("{}")` and `JSON.parse(null)` work. Depending on what `carts` should look like and where you're using it, you should use: 
`cart: [JSON.parse(localStorage.carts || default)]` where `default` is either `"{}"`, `"[]"` or `null`.

Comment: You know, I should add Pinia persisted state was forked from vuex persisted state. You can use it, but it's deprecated. Which, if you don't care about using vuex, I doubt you care about it being deprecated. I am still confused as to what data you're seeing about hardcoded data. Tbh, if we're unable to fix this here, it would help a lot to make a code sandbox

Comment: Your store has serious problems. In some mutations you're setting state properties which don't exist. Also, you have getters returning a state prop (which means they're useless, you could just use the state prop directly). This indicates you don't fully understand what each part of a store does and how it should be used. You likely need to take a step back and perhaps watch a tutorial on how to use Vuex in Vue. I recommend Vue Mastery's [Intro to Vuex](https://www.vuemastery.com/courses/mastering-vuex/intro-to-vuex/), which is one of their free lessons.

Comment: @IgorMoraru, only partially correct: `JSON.parse(null)` is valid.